# Function of a line of code

Tags: python

For the following codes (which is used to generate a graph in IPython), what does  `if k in [0, len(n_trials) - 1] else None` do?

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#total figure size
figsize(11, 9)

import scipy.stats as stats

dist = stats.beta
n_trials = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 15, 50, 500]
data = stats.bernoulli.rvs(0.5, size=n_trials[-1])
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

# For the already prepared, I'm using Binomial's conj. prior.
for k, N in enumerate(n_trials):
    sx = plt.subplot(len(n_trials) / 2, 2, k + 1)
    plt.xlabel("$p$, probability of heads") \
        if k in [0, len(n_trials) - 1] else None
    #Make the y label not appeared
    plt.setp(sx.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    heads = data[:N].sum()
    y = dist.pdf(x, 1 + heads, 1 + N - heads)
    plt.plot(x, y, label="observe %d tosses,\n %d heads" % (N, heads))
    plt.fill_between(x, 0, y, color="#348ABD", alpha=0.4)
    plt.vlines(0.5, 0, 4, color="k", linestyles="--", lw=1)

    leg = plt.legend()
    leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)
    plt.autoscale(tight=True)


plt.suptitle("Bayesian updating of posterior probabilities",
             y=1.02,
             fontsize=14)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: the `\\` at the end the previous line tells you that this is a continuation of that line.

Comment: That's a really weird way to write that code. It doesn't even save lines.

Answer (score 5):

That code is misleading in a number of ways. As pointed out in the comments, the line you're asking about is a continuation of the previous line, because of the escaping backslash. It becomes:

```
plt.xlabel("$p$, probability of heads") if k in [0, len(n_trials) - 1] else None
```

Which is just a convoluted way of writing:

```
if k == 0 or k == len(n_trials) - 1:
    plt.xlabel("$p$, probability of heads")
```

The syntax `'True' if condition else 'False'` is [Python's version of the ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/645956), but there is no reason to use it in this case.

Comment: Urgh, the pythonic way! I think what your equivalent line is far more readable!

Comment: @SteveLorimer -- What do you mean by "pythonic"?  This way *is* the pythonic way to write it.  The original code is just silly ...

Comment: I wonder if the author of this code is normally a Ruby programmer? That syntax would be much more idiomatic in Ruby.